# Swift - Use of undeclared type 'GTMOAuth2Authentication'

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I'm switching an application from Obj-C to Swift where I have Google+ sign in implemented.

I have `GoogleOpenSource.framework` and `GooglePlus.framework` on my project, as well as the following lines on my bridging header:

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GPPSignIn.h>
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error `Use of undeclared type 'GTMOAuth2Authentication'` when trying to implement `- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error` on a `GPPSignInDelegate`.

I'm using G+ SDK 1.7.1, as well as the final version of Xcode 6.

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing one import from your bridging header - `GTMOAuth2Authentication` is a part of the `GoogleOpenSource` framework:

```
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
```

Comment: also make sure to select each framework/bundle and check the testing target and add imports to your testing bridging header if you are using a testing target